# CHMOD for directory only readable through ftp or script on server

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, chmod

What is the CHMOD for a directory I want to save files under only using a php - script on the same server. These files should only be readable using my ftp-software(i am admin) or the script.

Background is, I want to save backups of my mysql database there that are created using a php script and a cron-job. Nobody should have access to those but me.

Is it 770, 700, 600 or 660 or something different?

Do I need to set files under this directory with CHMOD aswell or are they not reachable once I set the rights of the upper directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the script as the same user you use for FTP then you just need:

```
chmod 700
```

If you there are two user accounts then you need a common group membership in which case the permissions will be

```
chmod 770
```

Comment: I found that to open a directory you need to set Execute aswell. I found 700 to be working with both.

Comment: Quite right! I had forgotten that. So I removed the updated section to be more correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the www-user (if that's the group of your php-/webserver) and the ftp-user in a common group. Then, the dir should have mod=`770`; i.e., writeable+readable+executable by *the user that owns the dir (you)* and *the aforementioned group*...

Explanation of the octets (i.e. the `7` mentioned above):

- `7`: writeable, readable and executable
- `5`: readable, executable
- `4`: readable
- `2`: writeable
- `1`: executable